# How can I make an output in radians with pi in it?

Tags: python, numpy, angle, pi, radians

I want to give out an angle in radians in python. I also know how to do that but is it posible to make the output like that 1 * pi instead of 3.14159 without programming it myself?

Thx for help.

Comment: divide by `pi` and you will get `1` and later you have to on your own display it as `1 * pi` - but `3.14159` is only aproxymation so you can get `1.1` or `0.9` instead of `1`. Eventually you can try to use module [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/) for symbolic math

Comment: also, note that there are some [constants (like pi) available in numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html)

Comment: there is no function to convert `3.14159` to string `1 * pi` and `6.28318` as `2*pi` and you would have to do it on your own (by divede by `pi`). Problem is that `pi` is only aproxymation and you can get `1.01 * pi` or `0.99 * pi` instead of `1 * pi`. For some angles you can simply use dictionary `{30: "PI/6", 45: "PI/4", 60: "PI/3", ... 180: "PI", ...}`. Because you have to use strings `"PI/6"`, `"PI/4"`, `"PI/3"` so you can even use strings `π/6, π/4, π/3`. WIkipedia: [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) has table with values.

Comment: BTW: based on wikipedia [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) `radian = angle/180 * pi` so you could use it do display with PI - `print(angle/180, "* pi")` before converting to `radian`

Comment: @furas The `0.01 * pi` or `0.99 * pi` issue can be avoided by looking for [best rational approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) of `angle/pi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this (cf **furas**'s comment) :

```
from math import pi

angle = 2*pi
angle_new_format = angle/pi
print("angle =", angle)
print("angle_new_format = {} * pi".format(angle_new_format))
```

Output :

```
angle = 6.283185307179586
angle_new_format = 2.0 * pi
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function, which will find a nice fraction of pi using `Fraction.limit_denominator`, and then cleans up the output to write "pi" instead of "pi/1" and "0" instead of "0.0 pi", etc.

```py
from math import pi
from fractions import Fraction

def rad_to_pifrac(rad, max_denominator=8000):
    pifrac = Fraction(rad / pi).limit_denominator(max_denominator)
    if pifrac == 0:
        return '0'
    num = {1: '', -1: '-'}.get(pifrac.numerator, str(pifrac.numerator))
    denom = '/{}'.format(pifrac.denominator) if pifrac.denominator != 1 else ''
    return 'pi'.join((num, denom))
```

By toying with the optional parameter `max_denominator` you can adjust between rounder fractions or more accurate fractions; for instance, `rad_to_pifrac(22/7, max_denominator=1000)` is `'pi'` but `rad_to_pifrac(22/7, max_denominator=2000)` is `'2001pi/2000'`.

Some tests:

```py
import sympy

def test_pi(max_denominator=100):
    testcases = ['0', '1', '22/7', '0.39', '0.393', '3', '3.14', 'pi/8', 'pi/4', '-pi/4', '3*pi/4', '-3*pi/4', '-pi', 'pi', '2*pi', '6.28']
    print('max_denominator={}'.format(max_denominator))
    for s in testcases:
        value = float(sympy.parse_expr(s).evalf())
        pifrac = rad_to_pifrac(value, max_denominator=max_denominator)
        print('{:10s} ----> {}'.format(s, pifrac))

>>> test_pi()
max_denominator=100
0          ----> 0
1          ----> 7pi/22
22/7       ----> pi
0.39       ----> 12pi/97
0.393      ----> pi/8
3          ----> 85pi/89
3.14       ----> pi
pi/8       ----> pi/8
pi/4       ----> pi/4
-pi/4      ----> -pi/4
3*pi/4     ----> 3pi/4
-3*pi/4    ----> -3pi/4
-pi        ----> -pi
pi         ----> pi
2*pi       ----> 2pi
6.28       ----> 2pi
```