# I'm looking to make a progam which returns trigonometric values for any input

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

Using latest version of Python
I'm using math module to calculate the trigonometric values but I'm not getting the Output I want.
Program:

> 

```
ans = math.sin(rad)
fracshun = ans.as_integer_ratio()
fracshun = str(fracshun[0])+"/"+str(fracshun[1])
print("sin", degree, "°", " = ", fracshun, " = ", ans, sep="")
```

when I calculate sin of degree 45, the desired output is 1/√2, but this isn't the output I am getting, instead I get this

> sin45.0° = 6369051672525773/9007199254740992 = 0.7071067811865476

And this is the case for other values like sin of 60 degree or cos of 30 degree and 45 degree
How to print number as fractions that includes square roots(How to get "1/√2" from "0.7071067811865476")?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. If you include code in your question, please only show relevant parts of the code. See [mre] for help. All these things about `yno` and `inow` and `input()` and `print()` and huge forests of `if elif` are not helpful at all, and very discouraging for anyone who wants to read your question.

Comment: Also note that `0.7071067811865476` is an approximate value of `1/√2`, which you can check by trying `from math import sqrt; print('1/√2 = ', 1/sqrt(2))`

Comment: @Stef The values are same but I want the output to be in the form 1/√2

Comment: So, your real question is "how to print number as fractions that includes square roots"? (How to get "1/√2" from "0.7071067811865476"? If so, please, edit your question to ask that (and remove all unrelated `input/while` menus and such, to keep a minimal example, for example showing `math.sqrt(1/2).as_integer_ratio()` and asking how to have it in the form `[1, √2]`

Comment: @chrslg ok ill do it. I'm new here.

Comment: `1/√2` is an irrational number so it is inevitable you will get a decimal approximation. You might want to look at the sympy module for symbolic math.

Comment: Note that `as_integer_ratio` wouldn't even work to give you a reduced fraction of integers. As docs shows, `3.14.as_integer_ratio()` is  `(7070651414971679L, 2251799813685248L)`, not `(314,100)` or even better `(157,50)`. `2251799813685248` is a power of 2. Because 3.14, in IEEE float representation is indeed `7070651414971679/2**51`. Most number would have that `2**51=2251799813685248` denominator.

Comment: @chrslg so what do i use instead of as_integer_ratio ?

Comment: I really don't know. Module `fractions` at least can work on decimals, or even floats but with a denominator limit, and not just power of 2. `fractions.Fraction(sin(pi/6)).limit_denominator(100)` is `Fraction(1,2)` for example. If your question is limited to fractions such as `1/√2`, and not `1/(1+√2)` for example, then, you could just use them with the square of your value. `fractions.Fraction(sin(pi/3)**2).limit_denominator(100)` is `Fraction(3,4)` for example, and from there, it is quite easy to deduce that `sin(pi/3)` is `√3/√4=√3/2`

Comment: Other option is, as already mentioned, to use sympy for symbolic computation

Comment: `sympy.sin(sympy.pi/4)`

Comment: Similar question: [How can I make an output in radians with pi in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059762/how-can-i-make-an-output-in-radians-with-pi-in-it)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using trigonometric functions from standard module `math`, you can use trigonometric functions from [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

sympy is a python module designed specifically for symbolic calculations. Calculations made with sympy won't evaluate into floating-point approximations unless you explicitly ask for it.

```py
>>> from sympy import pi, sin

>>> sin(pi/2)
1

>>> sin(pi/4)
sqrt(2)/2

>>> sin(pi/4).evalf()
0.707106781186548
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to note that we typically dislike having radicals in the denominator; and 1 / √2 = √2 / 2, so we typically prefer the latter.

Second, to express a floating-point number `x` as a multiple of √2, all you have to do is divide `x` by `sqrt(2)`:

```py
from math import sqrt

x = 0.7071067811865476
r = x / sqrt(2)
print('x = {} √2'.format(r))
# x = 0.5 √2
```

Now, you can see that the output is still showed with a decimal point, not with a fraction. Getting a fraction back from these floating-point numbers involves quite a bit of guessing, because floating-point numbers are approximations. For instance, you can "guess" that `0.5` is 1/2, and that `0.333` is 1/3. But `0.333` is not exactly equal to 1/3. How do we choose 1/3 rather than 3/10 or 33/100 or 333/1000?

Finding the "best fraction" corresponding to an approximate number is a topic that has been extensively studied. See this wikipedia article on the topic: [Best rational approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations).

In python, the algorithms described in this wikipedia article are implemented in the standard library, in method `Fraction.limit_denominator` of class `Fraction` in module `fractions`.

Here is a function I wrote which divide a number by `sqrt(2)` then uses `Fraction.limit_denominator` to find a best approximating fraction and display the result nicely:

```py
from math import sqrt
from fractions import Fraction

def float_to_sqrt2frac(x, max_denominator=40):
    y = Fraction(x).limit_denominator(max_denominator)
    r = Fraction(x / sqrt(2)).limit_denominator(max_denominator)
    if abs(y - x) <= abs(r*sqrt(2) - x):  # approximate as rational
        prettyones = {1: '1', -1: '-1'}
        m = ''
        r = y
    else:                                 # approximate as √2 fraction
        prettyones = {1: '', -1: '-'}
        m = '√2'
    if r == 0:
        return '0'
    else:
        num = prettyones.get(r.numerator, str(r.numerator))
        denom = '/{}'.format(r.denominator) if r.denominator != 1 else ''
        return m.join((num, denom))
```

You can toy around with the optional parameter `max_denominator` but if all your floating-point numbers were obtained as results of `math.cos`, `math.sin` or `math.tan` operations on relatively-precise angles, it shouldn't matter too much; and if the angles are too imprecise, you can't expect this function to guess whether the result should be a multiple of √2 or not anyway.

Some tests:

```py
import sympy

def test_sqrt2(max_denominator=40):
    testcases = ['0', '1', '0.7', '0.707', '0.707107', '0.47', '1.1', '1.06', '1.0606', '1.06066', '3*sqrt(2)/4', 'sqrt(2)/8', '-sqrt(2)/4', '12*sqrt(2)/19', '-3*sqrt(2)/7', 'sin(pi/6)', 'sin(-pi/6)', 'cos(pi/6)', 'cos(45 * pi / 180)', 'sin(0.79)', 'sin(0.785)', 'sin(0.7854)']
    print('max_denominator={}'.format(max_denominator))
    for s in testcases:
        value = float(sympy.parse_expr(s).evalf())
        z = float_to_sqrt2frac(value, max_denominator=max_denominator)
        print('{:13s} ----> {}'.format(s, z))

>>> test_sqrt2()
max_denominator=40
0             ----> 0
1             ----> 1
0.7           ----> 7/10
0.707         ----> √2/2
0.707107      ----> √2/2
0.47          ----> 8/17
1.1           ----> 11/10
1.06          ----> 35/33
1.0606        ----> 35/33
1.06066       ----> 3√2/4
3*sqrt(2)/4   ----> 3√2/4
sqrt(2)/8     ----> √2/8
-sqrt(2)/4    ----> -√2/4
12*sqrt(2)/19 ----> 12√2/19
-3*sqrt(2)/7  ----> -3√2/7
sin(pi/6)     ----> 1/2
sin(-pi/6)    ----> -1/2
cos(pi/6)     ----> 13/15
cos(45 * pi / 180) ----> √2/2
sin(0.79)     ----> 27/38
sin(0.785)    ----> √2/2
sin(0.7854)   ----> √2/2
```